# knife bootstrap windows winrm from Mac OS X workstation fails

Tags: windows, chef-infra, knife

Running the command `knife bootstrap windows winrm ec2box.amazonaws.com -r 'role[web]' -x Administrator -P 'mypassword'` from my Mac OS X workstation produces the output below. Running it from a Windows workstation, the command successfully runs. Is there an extra step I need to take to get my Mac OS X workstation to communicate via WinRM correctly?

I'm using this on Amazon's Windows Server 2012 AMI. It printed `#39` everywhere on my terminal, not an artifact of Stack Overflow.

```
WARNING: Could not load IOV methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update
WARNING: Could not load AEAD methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update
Bootstrapping Chef on ec2box.amazonaws.com
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 1"
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 2"
ec2box.amazonaws.com '#39' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
ec2box.amazonaws.com operable program or batch file.
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 3"
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 4"
ec2box.amazonaws.com '#39' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
ec2box.amazonaws.com operable program or batch file.
ec2box.amazonaws.com '#39' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
ec2box.amazonaws.com operable program or batch file.
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 5"
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 6"
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 7"
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 8"
ec2box.amazonaws.com "Rendering &#39;C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\bootstrap-7738-1370535154.bat&#39; chunk 9"
ec2box.amazonaws.com
ec2box.amazonaws.com else was unexpected at this time.
ec2box.amazonaws.com C:\Users\Administrator>mkdir C:\chef
ec2box.amazonaws.com
ec2box.amazonaws.com C:\Users\Administrator>(
ec2box.amazonaws.com echo.url = WScript.Arguments.Named("url")
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.path = WScript.Arguments.Named("path")
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.proxy = null
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objUserVariables = wshShell.Environment("USER")
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.On Error Goto 0
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objXMLHTTP.open "GET", url, false
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objXMLHTTP.send()
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objADOStream.Open
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objADOStream.Type = 1
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objADOStream.Position = 0
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.If objFSO.Fileexists(path) Then objFSO.DeleteFile path
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objFSO = Nothing
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objADOStream.SaveToFile path
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.objADOStream.Close
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objADOStream = Nothing
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.End if
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
ec2box.amazonaws.com ) 1>C:\chef\wget.vbs
ec2box.amazonaws.com
ec2box.amazonaws.com C:\Users\Administrator>(
ec2box.amazonaws.com echo.param(
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.   [String] $remoteUrl,
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.   [String] $localPath
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.)
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient;
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.
ec2box.amazonaws.com  echo.$webClient.DownloadFile($remoteUrl, $localPath);
ec2box.amazonaws.com ) 1>C:\chef\wget.ps1
ec2box.amazonaws.com C:\Users\Administrator>) else (
```

Comment: What's the output of `gem list |grep knife`? What version of Windows? Are you using Amazon's AMIs, or your own?

Also, did it show '&#39;' all over the place in your terminal, or is that an artifact of Stack Overflow?

Comment: @henry - Updated my question. I'm using this on Amazon's Windows Server 2012 AMI. It printed #39 everywhere on my terminal, not an artifact of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work with knife-windows 0.5.10 [tested with windows server 2008R2]

Install it with:

```
gem uninstall knife-windows
gem install knife-windows -v 0.5.10
```

check your gems with:

```
gem list|grep knife-windows
```

And it should show:

```
knife-windows (0.5.10)
```

Comment: @themathmagician: What version of ruby did you install with chef?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue. What i did was:

Uninstall gem and then did aptitude update, and then installed gem & knife windows pluggin in this loaction(/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-windows), and opened the 5985 port and configured the winrm:

```
  1.winrm quickconfig -q   
  2.winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}  
  3.winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}  
  4.winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}   
  5.winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
```

and then bootstrapped:

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm ec2-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -r 'recipe[cookbook]' -x Administrator -P xxxxxxxx -N "WIN-xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with #39 characters on my OSX, see my description of it: [Stuck trying to bootstrap Windows server using Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863582/stuck-trying-to-bootstrap-windows-server-using-chef)

In my case, rvm was the responsible culprit.

I managed to resolve this issue by following steps: 
1) downloading and running the omnibus installer

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

2) Disabling rvm by using system ruby:

```
rvm use system
```

3)installing knife-windows directly in chefs library:

```
sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-windows
```

This, together with configuring the Windows 2008 server as recommended on  https://github.com/opscode/knife-windows
(commands available in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jimcroft/3878113)
did the trick, and I could bootstrap my node :)
Agata

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem may be related to poor interoperability between Ruby 2.x and the winrm gem:

https://github.com/WinRb/WinRM/pull/73