# knife windows bootstrap winrm from Mac OS X fails chef client

Tags: windows, chef-infra, knife, winrm

Similiar issue to: [knife bootstrap windows winrm from Mac OS X workstation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967163/knife-bootstrap-windows-winrm-from-mac-os-x-workstation-fails)

I downgraded to version 0.5.10 and got slightly further, but it does not seem to recognise the chef-client and install it. I am using Mac OS X:

```
) 1>C:\chef\wget.vbs 

C:\Users\Administrator>cscript /nologo C:\chef\wget.vbs /url:http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.msi /path:C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chef-client-latest.msi 
CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (0x800A0007)

C:\Users\Administrator>msiexec /qb /i C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chef-client-latest.msi 
This installation package could not be opened.  Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

C:\Users\Administrator>(
echo.-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----  
echo.-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
) 1>C:\chef\validation.pem 

C:\Users\Administrator>(
echo.log_level        :info  
echo.log_location     STDOUT  
echo. 
echo.chef_server_url  "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/company"  
echo.validation_client_name "company-validator"  
echo.client_key        "c:/chef/client.pem"  
echo.validation_key    "c:/chef/validation.pem"  
echo.file_cache_path   "c:/chef/cache"  
echo.file_backup_path  "c:/chef/backup"  
echo.cache_options     ({:path => "c:/chef/cache/checksums", :skip_expires => true})  
echo. 
echo.node_name "windows-boot-01" 
) 1>C:\chef\client.rb 

C:\Users\Administrator>(echo.{"run_list":["--verbose"]}) 1>C:\chef\first-boot.json 

C:\Users\Administrator>SET "PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\ruby\bin;C:\opscode\chef\bin;C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin" 
54.217.81.232 
C:\Users\Administrator>chef-client -c c:/chef/client.rb -j c:/chef/first-boot.json -E edge 
'chef-client' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `C:\opscode\chef` exist? Maybe it's a [PATH issue](http://docs.opscode.com/install_windows.html#path-system-variable).

Comment: what if "C:\opscode" in not created automatically after bootstrap? How can we create?